# RC filter in SPI MISO line

Tags: current, spi, emc, current-limiting, high-current

I have a question about SPI line. I have seen in several circuits that an RC filter (R in series and C is between the MISO line and ground). Does anyone know the usage of this filter in SPI MISO line? Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Show a few of those several circuits you have seen please. Don't forget to attribute the pictures.

Comment: Is the R located near the sending device?

Comment: What Andy said. Context, context, context: This is engineering. We don't "generally" do something, we do things like adding resistors and capacitors for *reasons*, and these arise from system and component properties, which we can't smell from your question :) To avoid that we'll just have to guess, we'd need to know in which applications and which devices at each end you've seen that. There's many many many possible answers.

Comment: Many thanks @MarcusMüller , I thought that this filter may be a general approach and that is why I have not provided the context. SPI frequency is 1 MHz and I do not see any thing which may be important, at least I am not professional to see those important details!

Comment: @user15847 I asked for more than the SPI frequency, and so did Andy. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: This model becomes significantly worse with a CMOS input capacitance of say 5 pF.

Comment: thing really is that the SPI clock frequency is nearly irrelevant to the EMI; signal edge speeds, transmission line length, driver strength, receiver matching, … are all more important features when it comes to adjusting trace impedance. We don't ask this stuff because we want to annoy you!

Comment: In my limited opinion, with the unidirectional lines of SPI, a series R can be helpful, but RC filter much less likely. Along the lines of Lorenzo's answer, with an off board connection, AC termination at the receiving end is a possibility, and could be mistaken for an RC filter.

Comment: @PeteW , many thanks for the answer. Why are is helpful?

Comment: [see here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.diodes.com/assets/App-Note-Files/AB023.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjK0b7HkuzuAhVNV80KHSazAxEQFjABegQIBBAF&usg=AOvVaw05hHVtvuQwkDuq1Kg9i0NU)  figure 4 shows AC termination. // whether or not you really need it (often not with common SPI applications) depends on your details

Answer (score 1):

You would need a properly attached 500MHz or better scope to see the ringing on a 1m cable with 5ns prop delay.

- SPI was never intended for long cables.
- this is a transmission line theory type question best understood by impedance ratios and stand wave ratios. Essentially 5:1 ratio cable:source R can cause >50% ringing
- Diode clamps dampen by overvoltage ESD protection diodes built into CMOS devices. This also improves reflections greatly in a cable.
- SPI comes in many configurations of open drain with pullup R and push-pull low impedance.
- SPI chips are designed to be slower (than std 74HC logic) and thus effectively have internal LPF with ~ >=100 ns prop delay.  Clock speeds on IC's are rated from 0.4 to 26MHz so your results may vary with pullup R.

There is no obvious benefit from an RC filter, but other factors not mentioned may or may not impact this at maximum cable lengths and high bit rate.

- a 1m cable only has ~ 5ns prop delay.

[here interactive switches using 1m cable](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CMEwDoBMBOSAWS96VQHYx1VFCoJJKAoeQ%20EeVADhAGZUIss3OkocdCFSQILJDQDuICSCxgIzNgskys6AGwcu8rSJZsw0%20b3mKorc5IBOIWGfbttEJy9oBzWdwtys8d2MAJXtHZ3s5N3ARJkU4iFRkakTqJCSaAGNLPl0CFQsqOGYoZHjeFl4uAKx2cFKweBoAZT1tVhUzduiIADMAQwAbAGdoaNQaOx42IlRTPjAsaKdjGU1F-iYrDeMWjTbDbIMjJhB%204dGEmgAPeUIKdlxKbQfFxdRFoKvrkHR5tmZ1nh5CJFgAVL43LjCJyvB4cdgURYBERiAA6QwA8gALAC26MgADshgAadHwPFDPoABypNgA9ldkOipABLGzQIbfSBwjCMQhYWYYV5MRYsgkAF2gNj6GXFLIAbtB0U0AAoAEVB6KGrPFGSxHPRAAoWQATaCDACUzRAax0Am20TOIzGE1C80WrgWS0UJgc7rd8Jc31gLGexHskGhhFqSI96MAlcDo4PMQXhzrR4HwUUSqUyuWK9FanV6g1DY1my2ZG3rcK21TRGAIWYoOLoNvtjttg4tho0IbVu0DqJKU6DEYmPwWOsFGgm1oiMBsPIL6ZMABykAYjRCy64S6s8FI3XMUGPKEgs-ktr385vs3gG63NC8WGvi6vb3e3T7t4Ut8g7iME60AmHsK6-mo-7aGBXTGDciBtKgswbEh1BIrMADqbIcsS2osrq%20pDIWlLsuiprmgM6IEnSBKwGKJoAK6ygqIHqI4XpTIOKyHOwXrLtsz5zNYQn%20IENAhPWvGvBYsHRH%20qTdOkkwWFJQmqdwxDGHSmZyS8TDIG2YAIhgDS-GsGB1HEjAJMCtRopiuI0NpiAnNwzj3igqDOOgArvFMPCEC49QNGMsQcCA4JOTE1nyO5sSlJo3IYJG1SLr8lmKDFgrhZ8NBAA) with 50 Ohm source and 5pF load and dominant ringing at 40MHz.
[image]

Comment: not really agree with the 'spi are designed for low frequency' and never seen an open drain one. 100% spot on the rest

Comment: (400 kHz max to 26 MHz relative low ;) If you recall the invention by MOT and the subsequent history or read WIki history, you may understand the BW was intentionally limited for short haul and low frequency (<30MHz) relative to other methods  Open drain types https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/interface-i-o-expanders/749?s=N4IgjCBcoCwdIDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGYAOAJjBgFYQBdAgBwBcoQBldgJwCWAOwDmIAL4Ew9GFFDJI6bPiKkQMAAwA2MNuZtOkHv2FjJISho1ykqTLgLFIZaloCyACQBe%2BkBy4AqkIC7ADyKG44aFgArnw4EubUalisAsziQA  (updates Answer to give relative to)

Comment: ah ok, the *original* SPI :D even 8 MHz is difficult to pull on 20cm if it's split without buffers. Interference between reflections on the Y point destroys the signal. As a rule I only make point-to-point SPIs, if needs to be multipoint (multiple CS, usually), I put a buffer on each branch

Comment: Due to trace & device load capacitance, A series matched R to cable impedance improves response.  But attenuates amplitude done at all ends. Thus ring topology with short stubs and endpoint active termination. e.g. like some SCSI bus but then not SPI. There are other methods with series R and higher voltage drivers

Answer (score 0):

It *could* help for very long or noisy line or to stabilize it when the peripheral is 3-stated (not selected). However it will limit the maximum rate.

I never seen it but IMHO it could be useful when the SPI is going off board thru a cable (not necessarily a good idea).

If such a filter is on the MOSI and SCLK lines too it could be to reduce EMI.